# How to use Bayesian statistics to estimate mean and a covariance matrix given structured observations

Tags: correlation, bayesian

I have a real-world problem in which the observations are linear combinations of elements in a vector $\bf{c}$. However, there exist correlation between different element in $\bf{c}$.

For example $\bf{c} = (c_1,c_2)^{\top}$ and $B = {\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{1.0}&{1.0}\\
0&{1.9}\\
{5.6}&0\\
 \vdots & \vdots\\
{3.2}&{0.5}
\end{array}} \right]_{(n \times 2)}}$ and observation $y=[\vdots]_{(n\times 1)}$ (number of observations is $n$).

In this case how can I estimate both the mean and covariance matrix if $c\sim\cal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$ (and in this case $y\sim\cal{N}(B\mu,B\Sigma B^{\top})$), in particular when the dimension of $c$ is high.

The parameters of interest are $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ (the mean and covariance of $c$).

Comment: Is $B$ assumed known?  The title says "Bayesian".  Does this mean you want a posterior distribution over $\mu$ and $\Sigma$?  If not, what is Bayesian about this problem?

Comment: Yes, $B$ is known. And the question is about estimate both $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ given $B$ and $y$. Bayesian is not directly related but I assume it is good to get results and CIs.